# Selecting to View only certain rows in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView of a set of Data, and I want to choose to only 'see' certain rows on parameters from the form, this shrinks the list to make my choice easier..

```
i.e.    ComboBox has two choices -> "aaa" and "bbb"
=====

Column1 | Column 2
aaa     | 123
aaa     | 234
bbb     | 345
bbb     | 456
aaa     | 567
bbb     | 678
```

After choosing the ComboBox as "aaa", I should get the results

```
Column1 | Column 2
aaa     | 123
aaa     | 234
aaa     | 567
```

This should allow me to click the row to bring the info from that row into a seperate form..

BUT the original data has to remain the same.. I don;t want to change it, just view it differently..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a LINQ datasource you could filter based on if combobox has selection.

```
var result = from i in MyDataContext select i.Col1, i.Col2

if (! String.IsNullOrEmpty(cbComboBox1.Text))
{
   result = from i in result where i.Col1 == cbComboBox1.Text
            select i;
}
```

If you are not using a LINQ datasource you could use LINQ to apply the filter to the already databound DataGridView by using this in the indexchanged event. You will also need to write something to remove the filter again too for when you want to show all data.

```
if (! string.IsNullOrEmpty(cbComboBox1.Text))
{
    var result = from DataGridViewRow row in dgvData.Rows
                 where row.Cells["Column1"].Value as string != cbComboBox1.Text
                 select row.Index;

    foreach (var i in result)
    {
        dgvData.Rows[i].Visible = false;
    }
}
```